# Python object exceeds recursion depth

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm writing this program to process some lab results for college written in a .txt file. However, when I launch the program,it says there's a recursion error and the python object exceeds recursion depth. How can I solve this?

```
from math import *
from numpy import *

D=0.946
iD=0.001

diametros=loadtxt("bolas.txt",delimiter=",")
ind=loadtxt("incertezas.txt",delimiter=",")    
for d in diametros :
    for incertd in ind:    
        a=1+(9*d/(4*D))+(9*d/(4*D))**2
        def incerteza(D,d,incertd,iD):
            incert= sqrt((((9/(4*D))+(9*d/(2*D**2))*incertd)**2+(((-9*d/(4*D**2))+(-9*d/(2*D**3)))*iD)**2))
            return incerteza(D,d,incertd,iD);
        j=incerteza(D,d,incertd,iD)
        r.append(a)
        i.append(j)
print (r,i)
```

Comment: `incerteza` calls itself infinitely. What's your intent there? Did you mean to add a base case in there?

Comment: I have thought that maybe it was the problem, but I don`t know why.  I just want to define a mathematical function

Comment: Why is `incerteza` calling itself though? Is the mathematical definition recursive?

Comment: I have no idea why,but it is not supposed to be recursive. I`m sorry for me being a little sluggish. I just have already rewritten it several times, and IDK whats wrong

Comment: What are you basing the function on? If it's not supposed to be recursive, it shouldn't be calling itself.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is in here:

```
def incerteza(D,d,incertd,iD):
            incert= sqrt((((9/(4*D))+(9*d/(2*D**2))*incertd)**2+(((-9*d/(4*D**2))+(-9*d/(2*D**3)))*iD)**2))
            return incerteza(D,d,incertd,iD);
```

The function `incerteza` keeps calling itself, *with the exact same parameters*, over and over and over again.

Maybe you meant to `return incert` ?